# Xamarin Forms iOS: Shell not showing element in a page with Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am also facing the issue mentioned here ([Xamarin Forms iOS RootViewController.View.AddSubview() not showing element in a page with Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71889011/xamarin-forms-ios-rootviewcontroller-view-addsubview-not-showing-element-in-a)) since last week while using Xamarin Forms shell and it fails to display when I set `Shell.PresentationMode="ModalAnimated"`. I have also tried using the traditional method but it didn't work for me. The interesting thing is that it is being pushed in ModalStack.

Does anyone have any workaround for this problem?

I have tried traditional navigation where a page is pushed onto the stack so a new page pops up over the current page but it didn't work for me.

Comment: `while using Xamarin Forms shell and it fails to display` I did a test ,but I can't reproduce this problem.  The shell could show elements in every page.  I tested on ios 15.5.   You can try to update your visual studio to the latest version.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT, I am using the latest version of VS 2022, but still facing it. If I use Xamarin Forms 5.0.0.1905, then it works perfectly fine but this version has some bugs which have been resolved in later updates.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. And you can try to post an issue about this problem.